# Not sure how to phrase: Rewriting a method from tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a custom MembershipUser and I have to overide the GetUser() method.

I'm following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx

Here is what I have:

```
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        CustomMembershipConext db = new CustomMembershipConext();

        var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userIsOnline)
        {
            user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;

        }

        return user;
        // Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication1.Models.User' to 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'

    }
}
```

I'm trying to replicate this:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT PKID, Username, Email, PasswordQuestion," +
        " Comment, IsApproved, IsLockedOut, CreationDate, LastLoginDate," +
        " LastActivityDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, LastLockedOutDate," +
        " IsSubscriber, CustomerID" +
        " FROM Users  WHERE Username = ? AND ApplicationName = ?", conn);

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = pApplicationName;

  OdbcMembershipUser u = null;
  OdbcDataReader reader = null;

  try
  {
    conn.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
      reader.Read();
      u = GetUserFromReader(reader);

      if (userIsOnline)
      {
        OdbcCommand updateCmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Users  " +
                  "SET LastActivityDate = ? " +
                  "WHERE Username = ? AND Applicationname = ?", conn);

        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastActivityDate", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = pApplicationName;

        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }

  }
  catch (OdbcException e)
  {
    if (WriteExceptionsToEventLog)
    {
      WriteToEventLog(e, "GetUser(String, Boolean)");

      throw new ProviderException(exceptionMessage);
    }
    else
    {
      throw e;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (reader != null) { reader.Close(); }

    conn.Close();
  }

  return u;      
}
```

Comment: shouldnt u be using `=` operator instead of `==`? like `user.IsOnline = userIsOnline;`

Comment: I think the problem is larger. I'm faking the "user.IsOnline" that never actually agreed.

Comment: but you do have a point!

Comment: Its a property with only a `get` property: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline.aspx`

Comment: I edited the question with your correction. At least the error is a little more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user is not of Type user, it is still an IQueryable<...>. You need to pull out your user object from the query result:

```
var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is very helpful, so if I want to replicate the code from the tut above I would do this: `public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            CustomMembershipConext db = new CustomMembershipConext();

            var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userIsOnline)
            {
                user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;

            }

            return user;
        }
    }` **Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication1.Models.User' to 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser**

Comment: Was that a question, or were you confirming that this solution works for you? If it works, feel free to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, that did answer the smaller question - the bigger question was how to rewrite the method from the tutorial link. I've gone ahead and accept your answer. I didn't know my question was going to be so loaded.

Comment: Ah, well we at least solved the problem according to how the post was titled. Good luck!